# NLTK word tokenizer crashes dosent even work what should i do it gives a big error i dont understand?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

So I was working on my first sentiment analysis project and I tried to use a word tokenizer by using the function
nltk.word_tokenizer(example)

also used another syntax
didn't work and got an error, searched for the error but realized it might be an issue with the library itself

the code cell i wrote

```
example = df['Text'][50]
print(example)
type(example)
nltk.word_tokenize(example)
nltk.word_tokenize()
```

the error

```
{
    "name": "LookupError",
    "message": "\n**********************************************************************\n  Resource \u001b[93mpunkt\u001b[0m not found.\n  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n\n  \u001b[31m>>> import nltk\n  >>> nltk.download('punkt')\n  \u001b[0m\n  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html\n\n  Attempted to load \u001b[93mtokenizers/punkt/english.pickle\u001b[0m\n\n  Searched in:\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu/nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\share\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\lib\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'D:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'E:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - ''\n**********************************************************************\n",
    "stack": "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;31mLookupError\u001b[0m                               Traceback (most recent call last)\n\u001b[1;32md:\\practiceprograms\\sentiment_analysis.ipynb Cell 9\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;36m<cell line: 1>\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;32m----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/d%3A/practiceprograms/sentiment_analysis.ipynb#ch0000010?line=0'>1</a>\u001b[0m nltk\u001b[39m.\u001b[39;49mword_tokenize(example)\n\u001b[0;32m      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/d%3A/practiceprograms/sentiment_analysis.ipynb#ch0000010?line=1'>2</a>\u001b[0m nltk\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mword_tokenize()\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\sudhu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\tokenize\\__init__.py:129\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mword_tokenize\u001b[1;34m(text, language, preserve_line)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    114\u001b[0m \u001b[39mdef\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mword_tokenize\u001b[39m(text, language\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39menglish\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m, preserve_line\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m\u001b[39mFalse\u001b[39;00m):\n\u001b[0;32m    115\u001b[0m     \u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    116\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    Return a tokenized copy of *text*,\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    117\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    using NLTK's recommended word tokenizer\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    127\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    :type preserve_line: bool\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    128\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    \"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 129\u001b[0m     sentences \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m [text] \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m preserve_line \u001b[39melse\u001b[39;00m sent_tokenize(text, language)\n\u001b[0;32m    130\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m [\n\u001b[0;32m    131\u001b[0m         token \u001b[39mfor\u001b[39;00m sent \u001b[39min\u001b[39;00m sentences \u001b[39mfor\u001b[39;00m token \u001b[39min\u001b[39;00m _treebank_word_tokenizer\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mtokenize(sent)\n\u001b[0;32m    132\u001b[0m     ]\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\sudhu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\tokenize\\__init__.py:106\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36msent_tokenize\u001b[1;34m(text, language)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m     96\u001b[0m \u001b[39mdef\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39msent_tokenize\u001b[39m(text, language\u001b[39m=\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39menglish\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m):\n\u001b[0;32m     97\u001b[0m     \u001b[39m\"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m     98\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    Return a sentence-tokenized copy of *text*,\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m     99\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    using NLTK's recommended sentence tokenizer\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m   (...)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    104\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    105\u001b[0m \u001b[39m    \"\"\"\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 106\u001b[0m     tokenizer \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m load(\u001b[39mf\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39mtokenizers/punkt/\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;49;00mlanguage\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;49;00m\u001b[39m.pickle\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m)\n\u001b[0;32m    107\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m tokenizer\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mtokenize(text)\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\sudhu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\data.py:750\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mload\u001b[1;34m(resource_url, format, cache, verbose, logic_parser, fstruct_reader, encoding)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    747\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mprint\u001b[39m(\u001b[39mf\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m<<Loading \u001b[39m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;00mresource_url\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m>>\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m)\n\u001b[0;32m    749\u001b[0m \u001b[39m# Load the resource.\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 750\u001b[0m opened_resource \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m _open(resource_url)\n\u001b[0;32m    752\u001b[0m \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mformat\u001b[39m \u001b[39m==\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mraw\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m:\n\u001b[0;32m    753\u001b[0m     resource_val \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m opened_resource\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mread()\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\sudhu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\data.py:876\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36m_open\u001b[1;34m(resource_url)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    873\u001b[0m protocol, path_ \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m split_resource_url(resource_url)\n\u001b[0;32m    875\u001b[0m \u001b[39mif\u001b[39;00m protocol \u001b[39mis\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mNone\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mor\u001b[39;00m protocol\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mlower() \u001b[39m==\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mnltk\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m:\n\u001b[1;32m--> 876\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m find(path_, path \u001b[39m+\u001b[39;49m [\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39;49m])\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mopen()\n\u001b[0;32m    877\u001b[0m \u001b[39melif\u001b[39;00m protocol\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mlower() \u001b[39m==\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39mfile\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m:\n\u001b[0;32m    878\u001b[0m     \u001b[39m# urllib might not use mode='rb', so handle this one ourselves:\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m    879\u001b[0m     \u001b[39mreturn\u001b[39;00m find(path_, [\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m])\u001b[39m.\u001b[39mopen()\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mc:\\Users\\sudhu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\data.py:583\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mfind\u001b[1;34m(resource_name, paths)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    581\u001b[0m sep \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m*\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m \u001b[39m*\u001b[39m \u001b[39m70\u001b[39m\n\u001b[0;32m    582\u001b[0m resource_not_found \u001b[39m=\u001b[39m \u001b[39mf\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;00msep\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;00mmsg\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m{\u001b[39;00msep\u001b[39m}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[39m\"\u001b[39m\n\u001b[1;32m--> 583\u001b[0m \u001b[39mraise\u001b[39;00m \u001b[39mLookupError\u001b[39;00m(resource_not_found)\n\n\u001b[1;31mLookupError\u001b[0m: \n**********************************************************************\n  Resource \u001b[93mpunkt\u001b[0m not found.\n  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n\n  \u001b[31m>>> import nltk\n  >>> nltk.download('punkt')\n  \u001b[0m\n  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html\n\n  Attempted to load \u001b[93mtokenizers/punkt/english.pickle\u001b[0m\n\n  Searched in:\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu/nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\share\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'c:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\lib\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\sudhu\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'C:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'D:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - 'E:\\\\nltk_data'\n    - ''\n**********************************************************************\n"
}
```

Comment: That message would be a lot easier to read if you printed it out on the console. I don't know what IDE you are using, but it's definitely not helping you.

Comment: Anyway, what NLTK is trying to tell you is that you haven't installed a tokeniser (`punkt`). In order to tokenise, you need the tokeniser.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and this worked for me.
Open python script ( type `python` in terminal or Command Prompt ).

Go on ahead and do this:

```
import nltk
```

Hit enter.

```
nltk.download("puntk")
```

Hit enter.